# "You must choose at least one payment method" issue in M2E ebay listing

Tags: magento, m2e-pro

Error:

```
You must choose at least one payment method.
```

I have chosen Postal order/Banker's cheque but still i am getting above error.

Please suggest how can i fix this .

Answer (score 0):

Go to `system > configuration > payment method >` make sure that the correct payment methods are selected and then press `save`, do the same with Payment services and press `save`, and then go back to M2E and everything should be fine.

Hopefully this will work